# CSS Styling for a Page/ Site made with Pagelines

Tags: pages, css, code

I know how to change the HTML of page inside wordpress but for some reason I can't find the CSS for the page I'm looking for. I can find a huge amount of code made by Pagelines(Is it in there?). The website I'm working on has been used by another author who did basic coding for the site and styling. All I want to do is make some small changes in the CSS for the page. Where do I find that code?

Comment: If it's not in your-theme/style.css, then the answer is entirely dependent on the theme you are using.

Comment: Are you talking about Appearance/theme/style.css?

Comment: I don't know what you are referring to with Appearance/theme/style.css. If you can edit your theme directly through Admin - via Appearance -> Editor - then the editor will default to your currently active theme's style.css.

Comment: I meant from the wordpress menu bar on the left side. Can I view the CSS from one of these options on that bar?

Comment: As I said, Appearance -> Editor. It is possible that Editor is not available, though.

Comment: @vancoder alright so I'm in Editor. There are a lot of templates to the right of the screen. Is this were I would find my code?

Comment: In general, your css will be in `style.css`. As I said, this should be open by default when you go to Editor. But also note that this is in general - it ain't necessarily so, as your theme may do things differently.

Comment: Yeah I opened it and there is a **PHAT** bit of code right there. It says something about Pagelines?

Comment: Oh man - Pagelines is a theme/framework for WordPress, that I've had problems with before. You should be able to do some CSS editing through Pageline's own admin interface, but beyond that I can't tell you specifics. Pagelines is a monster.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8424/discussion-between-seth-urquhart-and-vancoder)

Comment: You might want to reword your title/question here, to mention Pagelines specifically, so someone with more experience of it can help.

Answer (score 0):

The primary stylesheet for a theme is usually `/wp-content/themes/themename/style.css`. That would be the first place to look. That file has to exist, but may be mostly empty and other stylesheets can be loaded by both theme and plugin. Some themes have very complicated stylesheet structures.

The easiest way to find the stylesheets is with a FireFox add-on called JSView. It will create a list of all of the stylesheets and Javascript files for you. FireBug will locate the stylesheets for you as well, if you right click and "inspect element with Firebug". You can also [`grep`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grep) your theme directory for `wp_register_script` or `wp_enqueue_script`.

Comment: where would I find "/wp-content/themes/themename/style.css"? I am the biggest wordpress noob ;)

Comment: That _is_ where you find the stylesheet. Log in to your host over FTP, open the `wp-content` directory, then the `themes` directory, find your theme directory and open it, and you should see `style.css`.

Comment: What is FTP? Is that the log in page to wordpress?

Comment: _Or_, he could just use Appearance -> Editor.

Comment: True, but I am very, very anti-editor. That thing is dangerous, like working on an airplane while it is in the air.

Comment: @s_ha_dum turns out he has Pagelines anyway, so all bets are off.